# best practice for Single-Page Applications to access API's to avoid CORS across domains

Tags: nginx, cors

here is the setup:

having a onpage app living on **example.com** which should access the API on the domain **api.example.com** via AJAX.

due to the CORS restriction i cannot access the API directly with Ajax, what is the best practice for this solution?

my first idea:

reverse proxy setup on **example.com** which reroutes all **example.com/api/(.*)** requests to 
**api.example.com/$1**

does anybody have a better idea and/or nginx exampels to solve this problem?

Comment: The best practice is to simply set the correct `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on api.example.com so that you can access the resources you need from example.com see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: which would result in a pre OPTIONS request for some API calls, which would "slow down" the app. see https://www.soasta.com/blog/options-web-performance-with-single-page-applications/

Comment: Have you found anything to your issue?